# Is this app-recommendation question on topic?

Tags: discussion

As a general rule, we as a site don't allow for anime recommendation questions, and according to our [help page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), we recommend avoiding questions that include "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”"

However, recently, this question was asked: [Looking for manga apps which filter out mature content](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20621/looking-for-manga-apps-which-filter-out-mature-content). The question is clearly asking for a list, which could potentially be too broad or just end up opening up questions about what counts as mature content, etc.

On the other hand, [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/what-databases-and-listing-sites-exist-for-anime-manga-etc?answertab=active#tab-top) exists, and it is also a list answer. However, it is clearly stated in the question that it exists to act as a canonical reference for the site, which isn't the case (from what I can tell) from the app question.

I just want to clarify: is the app-recommendation question on-topic/allowed, and if so, why?

Comment: I don't think recommendation is on topic, but question about what legal apps exist should be.

Comment: We don't do recommendation questions (What should I watch? kind of questions). However, questions asking for sites to watch/read anime/manga legally are OK, and definitely helpful for people other than the OP. There can only be less than a handful questions of this type, and in case it turns into a mess, the mess is contained and we can just clean it up easily.

Comment: @nhahtdh That makes sense, and it was basically what I assumed, but I mostly just wanted to confirm that.